# Basic classical linear error correcting code for bits exercice (from Nielsen & Chuang)

Tags: error-correcting-codes

I am learning about quantum error correction which is for a part based on classical linear error correcting code.

There is a very basic answer on an exercice I do not understand. Here is the problem (From Nielsen & Chuang, page 450, exercice 10.25)

> Let $C$ be a linear code. 
>   Show that if $x \in C^{\perp} $, then: $\sum_{y \in C} (-1)^{x.y} = |C|$
>   Show that if $x \notin  C^{\perp}$, then: $\sum_{y \in C} (-1)^{x.y}=0$

I can show the first one using the definition, basically if $x \in C^{\perp}$ by definition $\forall y \in C$ I have $x.y=0$

Thus: $\sum_{y \in C} (-1)^{x.y} = \sum_{y \in C} (-1)^0 = |C|$ (where I assume that what is called $|C|$ is the number of element in the linear code which is $2^k$ if we want to encode $k$ bits an information right ?

**However** I don't understand the second one. Indeed, if $x \notin C^{\perp}$ then $x.y=1$ (We work with modulo 2 scalar product). And we have:

$$\sum_{y \in C} (-1)^{x.y}=\sum_{y \in C} (-1)=-|C|$$

Where is my mistake ?

**In summary my questions are:**

- Do you agree with me that if we want to encode $k$ bits of info, then $|C|=2^k$
- Why for $x \notin C^{\perp}$ $\sum_{y \in C} (-1)^{x.y}=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $e_1, \ldots, e_k$ are (linearly independent) rows of the generator matrix of $C$. We can find vectors $e_{k+1}, \ldots, e_{n}$ s.t. $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a basis in $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ (not necessarily orthogonal).

$\textbf{Claim 1.}$ $\exists i \in [k],$ s.t. $\langle x, e_i \rangle = 1$. Otherwise, for $\forall y \in C$ the inner product $\langle x, y \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^k \beta_i \langle x, e_i \rangle = 0,$ where $y = \sum_{i=1}^k\beta_ie_i$ is the basis decomposition of $y$ (all operations are modulo 2). Hence, the assumption that $x \notin C^{\perp}$ is incorrect.

Without loss of generality, $\langle x, e_1\rangle = \ldots = \langle x, e_s\rangle = 1$, $\langle x, e_{s+1}\rangle = \ldots = \langle x, e_k\rangle = 0$ for some $s \in [k]$.

Then $\langle x, y\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^s\beta_i$. The number of sequences $\{\beta_i\}_{i=1}^s$ of an even weight is the same as the number of odd-weight sequences, and it's equal to $2^{s-1}$, which concludes the proof.